# VB.net program falling foul of InteropServices.COMException Bug

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.net program that I wrote and have used hundreds of times. Whilst using Windows 7 I "upgraded" to Office 2010 and IIRC had to make a few small changes to get it to work. I have now (and again I put it in quotes as I fail to see the benefits of calling it an upgrade !) "upgraded" to Windows 10 but went back to Office 2007 as I much prefer it. I am also using Visual Studio Community 2015. All of that may or may not be of help !!!

So, I run the program and it fails with the following error :

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   KA_Newsletter.exe
>
> Additional information: Word cannot open this document template.
>
> (L:...\Customize Ribbon Example 2.dotm)

I have looked up the error and there is a Microsoft page ...

[MS Support Bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815633)

... that suggests this may be a Bug, it explains why it may be happening and gives a resolution but I program for fun, I'm not an expert in VB at all and it may as well be written in Russian for all it helps me !!!

I also have no idea why Word should be trying to open that Example Template either, I copy a Template of my own to create a new Word document, this is pretty basic stuff !!! This is the relevant code, any help would be very much appreciated ...

```
Dim myNewsLetter As String
```

.
.
.

```
If File.Exists(myNewsLetter) Then
    'do nothing
Else
    myTemplate = myTempFolder & "KA_Newsletter.doc"
    File.Copy(myTemplate, myNewsLetter)
    Create_Blank_Newsletter()
End If
```

.
.
.

```
Private Sub Create_Blank_Newsletter()

    myMSWord = New Word.Application
    myMSDoc = myMSWord.Documents.Open(myNewsLetter) << <Error occurs on this line 
    myMSWord.WindowState= Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateNormal
    myMSWord.Visible= False
```

UPDATE :

Olaf, I updated the code as follows ...

```
myMSWord = New Word.Application

Dim inval As Object
'Marshal the object before passing it to the method.
inval = New System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispatchWrapper(myNewsLetter)
myMSDoc = myMSWord.Documents.Open(inval)

'myMSDoc = myMSWord.Documents.Open(myNewsLetter)
```

... but I am getting a similar error on the Open statement ...

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in KA_Newsletter.exe

Additional information: Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The MS page says you should try something like

```
Dim inval As Object
'Marshal the object before passing it to the method.
inVal = New System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispatchWrapper(myNewsLetter)
myMSDoc = myMSWord.Documents.Open(inval)
```

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long to get back to you ... I changed the code as follows ...

        myMSWord = New Word.Application

        Dim inval As Object
        'Marshal the object before passing it to the method.
        inval = New System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispatchWrapper(myNewsLetter)
        myMSDoc = myMSWord.Documents.Open(inval)

        'myMSDoc = myMSWord.Documents.Open(myNewsLetter)